# How can I permit only certain users to ssh?

Tags: ssh

In a system where all personnel have ssh connectivity,
is it safe to use 
`AllowUsers $USER` 
in /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

I want all the personnel to have ssh access, but I don't want system accounts to have ssh permissions. I would also like to set that up with out having to perpetually add users to the config file. Is there a variable I could use instead? If I assume username == user home, then maybe AllowUsers `ls /home/`
would work. I'm not sure if I should do that.

Comment: Use AllowGroups, put actual humans in a group for humans.

Comment: As DopeGhosti suggested, `AllowGroups` and put the (many?) humans in a group.  Or use `DenyGroups` to put the (fewer?) system accounts in a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the opposite.  Use DenyUsers in sshd_config to prevent logins by the users in the list.

The list of users you would deny login capabilities will generally be the superuser and any users who have /bin/nologin as their shell.  In addition examine your /etc/passwd file and determine any user who's installed as part of a package.  On CentOS 7, those users will generally have uids less than 1000.

Here's mine on CentOS 7:

```
DenyUsers root bin daemon adm lp sync shutdown halt mail operator games ftp nobody dbus polkitd tss colord usbmuxd rpc rtkit qemu radvd ntp chrony abrt avahi-autoipd unbound rpcuser nfsnobody libstoragemgmt saslauth pulse gdm gnome-initial-setup avahi pcp postfix sshd oprofile tcpdump lightdm openvpn nm-openconnect
```

I got that list by running an awk script I call "denyusers.awk":

```
./denyusers.awk /etc/passwd
```

Here's the source for my "denyusers.awk" script.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=":";
    printf("%s","DenyUser root");
}

{
    username=$1;
    uid=$3
    shell=$7;
    if ((uid<1000) || ( shell == "/sbin/nologin" )) {
       printf(" %s", username);
    }
}

END {
    print "";
}
```